# Question on apparent super efficiency of the magnetic penrose process

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, astrophysics

Accordingly to this paper $[1]$, the efficiency of the so called Magnetic Penrose Process (MPP) is, for supermassive black holes of mass $M∼10^{10} M_{\odot}$ immersed in a magnetic field having $B∼10^4G$:

$$\eta_{MPP} \approx 10^{12}. \tag{1}$$

Thus, the MPP is clearly super efficient. I'm wondering what is the catch behind this calculation, since this result cannot be a true physical prediction.
If you calculate the efficiency of the penrose process, without any external electromagnetic field, the efficiency drops to $29\%$ $[2]$. Hence, even though we can extract (rotational) energy from the black hole the process is bounded by $\eta < 1$, even in the case when $a = m$.

So, my question is:

**How can the MPP process be super efficient?**

> I think that we can say the result $(1)$ is true just when we look solely to the MPP itself, ignoring all the arguments of the astrophysical surroundings like the external magnetic field and so on. *Like when we say that a fusion reactor returns a positive energy output; however when the one consider all its surroundings: the power plant structure keeping fusion on, we readly see that the machine cannot export energy.*
>
> In the MPP case, however, is simpler (and different) than a fusion power plant, is just a kerr black hole immersed in a external magnetic field; this certainly is a common scenario for astrophysical black holes.

---

$[1]$
Zdenek Stuchlík, Martin Kološ and Arman Tursunov. *Penrose Process: Its Variants and Astrophysical Applications*. 2020. **Page 16, in the fourth line of the paragraph below equation $(75)$.**

$[2]$ Derek Raine. *Black Holes: An Introduction*. 2009.